# Is Java SE a prerequisite of Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am very new to programming and I am using Java as my first Programming Language. I am already using Java with Java SE for almost a week and I read something about Java EE and if I understood it correctly, Java EE = Java SE + other features, so I think I have to change my SDK to Java EE to save disk space.

I read the installation instructions about Java EE and it says there that its OK to have them both but I really wanted to have just Java EE. I uninstalled Java SE and installed Java EE but I was having some errors along the way and I can't continue installing Java EE. I can't remember what the errors were but I decided to cancel the installation. I installed Java SE again and installed Java EE and everything went smoothly. Now, I have both...

I am using JCreator 5 as my IDE and I configured it to use the Java EE jdk only. I tried to compile my test program but it seems that it cannot recognize it. How can I make my Java EE work without having Java SE.

I don't know whats going on. I am totally new to this. I just wanted to use J2EE... Please help.

Java SE is in C:\Program Files\Java while Java EE is in C:\Sun\AppServer

Comment: "Pls" is not a word.  Please break your question into clear paragraphs.  Please make your question very, very clear.  We don't really like trying to read a big block of confusing text.  Please simplify your question so we know what you're talking about.  When in doubt, please use real English.

Comment: J2SE/J2EE have been renamed/upgraded to Java SE and Java EE over 5 years ago. Please keep yourself up to date and don't read outdated documentation/books/tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java EE is defined by its specification and its specification is built on top on the Java SE classes . Java EE classes will call Java SE  classes  , so you cannot use the Java EE without the installation of Java SE . Otherwise , you will encounter the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: YEah!!! That's it!!! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is the error Im getting!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Java EE classes are defined over Java SE classes, so you need to install Java SE, first.

Happy learning!